# Count profitable customers

Tags: sql, count

I am a SQL newbie looking for help with this problem. I have a Postgres table like this

```
orders

id  | customer_name  | profit ($)
---------------------------------
0   | jimmy          | 5
1   | jimmy          | -2
2   | kate           | 3
...
```

I want to use SQL to get a list of customers who are profitable on net--that is, people whose entries in the profit category add up to a positive number. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like aggregation and having:

```
select customer_name, sum(profit)
from t
group by customer_name
having sum(profit) > 0;
```